# Deployment prices for Cassandra on AWS

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, cassandra-2.0

Until now we have been working with MySQL. But now we are trying to move for new DB i.e. Cassandra. Just I want to know approximate operating cost on Amazon EC2. As of now I dont have much knowledge of working with Cassandra. 
Requirments:

- 100 Write/Sec
- 100 Read/Second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are quite small. Even a single node EC2 node should be able to deal with it. However, for fault tolerance, you might want a slightly larger set-up. A good starting point might be two datacentres with five nodes each for an active active setup, with each DC being in a separate AZ. However, based on your fault tolerance needs, you might also go with five nodes in one AZ, with the other one having less (maybe three) serving as a backup. A good starting point may be to look at Instacluster, and deducing what's needed. And then managing your own clusters if you find it cost effective.